# Create a report from tables EMP and DEPT and format date to 'mm/dd/yyyy'

Tags: mysql, oracle11g, to-char

I am trying to create a report from table **EMP** and **DEPT** listing:

> MGR,DEPTNO(manager's department),DNAME(manager's department),EMPNO,ENAME,HIREDATE,SAL

This is what I have but I'm not sure if I did it correct or not. (The MGR column for an employee contains the EMPNO of his/her manager) Also how would I format the date to 'MM/DD/YYYY' I know i have to use TO_CHAR.

```
SELECT e.mgr,d.deptno,d.dname,e.empno,e.hiredate,e.sal  
FROM emp m, emp e, dept d WHERE e.mgr=m.empno and e.deptno=d.deptno;
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: The question is did I do this correctly or is it wrong?

Comment: Also how would I format the date to 'MM/DD/YYYY' I know i have to use TO_CHAR

Comment: Which database..Mysql or Oracle ??